# How can I change the Javascript so that the DOM script is also loaded with external Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've put together a gallery here. This works the way it should be. However, I have a problem with the script and had to share it. I was able to load part of it externally. I had to insert the other into the html document because otherwise the DOM apparently has not yet been loaded. How can I solve it that everything can pack externally?  Or maybe there is a better solution.

```js
document.getElementById("idRueck").addEventListener
("click", function() { move(bildIndex - 1); } );
document.getElementById("idVor").addEventListener
("click", function() { move(bildIndex + 1); } );

document.getElementById("idStart")
.addEventListener("click", start );
document.getElementById("idStop")
.addEventListener("click", stop );

let test = document.getElementById("wrapper");
test.addEventListener("mouseover", function(  ) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutVerweis);
    timeoutAktiv = false;}
, false);
test.addEventListener("mouseout", function(  ) {
    if(timeoutAktiv) return;
        timeoutAktiv = true;
        timeoutVerweis = setTimeout(
        function() {move(bildIndex+1);}, 500);}
, false);
```

```html
<script>
          const bild = ["http://placehold.it/350x150", "http://placehold.it/350x150",
          "http://placehold.it/350x150","http://placehold.it/350x150", "http://placehold.it/350x150"];
          let bildIndex = 0, timeoutVerweis, timeoutAktiv = false;

          function move(zahl)
          {
          bildIndex = zahl;
          if(bildIndex >= bild.length)
          bildIndex = 0;
          else if(bildIndex < 0)
          bildIndex = bild.length - 1;

          document.getElementById("idBild").src = bild[bildIndex];
          document.getElementById("idAusgabe").firstChild.nodeValue =
          (bildIndex+1) + "/" + bild.length;

          if(timeoutAktiv)
          timeoutVerweis = setTimeout(
              function() {move(bildIndex+1);}, 2000);
          }

          window.addEventListener("load", function() {
          if(timeoutAktiv) return;
          timeoutAktiv = true;
          timeoutVerweis = setTimeout(
          function() {move(bildIndex+1);}, 2000);  
          }
          )

          function start()
          {
          if(timeoutAktiv) return;
          timeoutAktiv = true;
          timeoutVerweis = setTimeout(
          function() {move(bildIndex+1);}, 2000);
          }

          function stop()
          {
          clearTimeout(timeoutVerweis);
          timeoutAktiv = false;
          }
        </script>        
        
        <div id="wrapper">
         <p><img style="width: 100%;" id="idBild" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Image"></p>
         <p>
         <input id="idRueck" type="button" value="<">
         <input id="idVor" type="button" value=">">

         <script>
            document.write("<span id='idAusgabe'>1/"
               + bild.length + "</span></p>");
         </script>
         <p><input id="idStart" type="button" value="Start">
         <input id="idStop" type="button" value="Stop"></p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting everything inside a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler ?

Comment: i'm looking at this. I'm still a beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `defer` tag such as:

```html
<script src="first js" defer></script>
<script src="second js" defer></script>
```

this will make the scripts execute in sequential order and *after* the page has loaded.

You can the details about this tag [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer)